# How to substitute variables names in C

Tags: c, string, random, strcpy

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    const char mot1[] = "POMME", mot2[] = "POIRE", mot4[] = "PASTEQUE", mot5[] = "MELON", mot6[] = "ORANGE", mot7[] = "FRAISE", mot8[] = "FRAMBOISE", mot9[] = "CITRON", mot10[] = "MANGUE";

    srand(time(NULL));

    int index = rand() % 10 + 1;

    char secret[100] = "";

    strcpy(motindex, secret);

    printf("Secret is now %s\n", secret);

    return 0;
}
```

Here's the code I made to generate a random secret word from a range of const char.

I want to substitute `index` in `strcpy(motindex, secret);`. How can I do that ?

Comment: Put the words into an array of pointers.  Then index into the array to select the desired word.

Comment: An array of pointers ? Coud you be more precise ?

Comment: Use `char *arr[] = {"word1", "word2", ...};`

Comment: Just as a sidenote, if you keep in mind, that variables names are compile-time thing, once the binary is there, there is no existence of a variable name, as such, maybe will help.

Answer (score 5):

You can't; strings are not identifiers and identifiers are not strings.
(Variable names don't even exist in the program - they only exist in the source code.)

Use an array and use the index as "name".

I also suspect that you want to copy the secret the other way around, so `secret` holds the name of a fruit.

```
int main()
{
    const char* mot[]= {"POMME", "POIRE", "PASTEQUE", "MELON", "ORANGE", "FRAISE", "FRAMBOISE", "CITRON", "MANGUE"};

    srand(time(NULL));
    int index = rand() % 9; /* You only have nine strings... */

    char secret[100] = "";

    strcpy(secret, mot[index]);

    printf("Secret is now %s\n", secret);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Okay, that's why, I inverted things in the `strcpy` function. Thanks for pointing that out. The result gave me the good answer. Only one question remaining : why using bidimensionnal array ? And why 128 ?

Comment: @Gradiuss I've edited the code to match what I believe you're after. (The two dimensions were necessary if you wanted to modify the strings, and 128 was a completely arbitrary "power of 2 that has plenty of room".)

Answer (score 2):

I think two-dim array can solve your problem
the codes list below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SC_NUM  10
int main(){
    const char motSecret[SC_NUM][100] = {
        "POMME",
        "POIRE",
        "PASTEQUE",
        "MELON",
       //some more const secret
    };

    int index = ((rand() % SC_NUM) + SC_NUM) % SC_NUM;
    char secret[100];
    strcpy(secret, motSecret[index]);
    printf("Secret is now %s\n", secret);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `((rand() % SC_NUM) + SC_NUM) % SC_NUM` is equivalent to `rand() % SC_NUM`.

Comment: Thanks for helping, unfortunately, secret is always `MELON` (the last one). So maybe you random function is not optimized.

Comment: @Gradiuss Google `srand`.

Comment: @molbdnilo, you are right. I I thought rand may return negative，but I read the rand man page(http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/?kw=rand) and find it return the value between 0 and RAND_MAX.

Comment: @Gradiuss you can add code `srand(time(NULL));`  to random the seed of rand.